# How to call a program and exit from the shell (the caller) when program is active?

Tags: linux, shell, opensuse

I want to run a program with GUI, by typing into `konsole`: `foo args …` and exit from the shell (that's the caller) when the program (`foo`) is active.

How do I this? Is there a Linux/Unix built-in command/program to do it? I'm not a shell-man, really. I know that it's possible by writing a small program in C or C++ (any other programming language with small I/O interface on POSIX) programming language with the `fork()` and one-of `exec*()` function family. It may take some time; I'll do it only if there is no native solution.

Sorry for my bad English; it's not my native language.
Also, not sure on tags, please edit for me, if I'm wrong.

If it matters, I'm using OpenSUSE 10.x.

Comment: Why do you need it? Do you know of any other program that behaves like this?

Comment: Because I want to open some programs by typing a single command on `konsole`; and when this programs is open, I don't need more of console open, but I couldn't close it because the console is the father of this program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nohup foo args &`

Will dissociate the command from the shell. Then you can exit. If `foo` produces any output, it will be placed in "nohup.out" in the current directory.

Comment: What's the name of `&'? it does exactly what I want to. I don't need realy of `nohup` program.

Comment: The `&` means to run the job in the background. [More info](http://www.hcidata.info/background-job.htm). Note that without `nohup`, it will still exit when the shell is closed.